# Add fake upload to tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a tinyMCE form where people can upload images.
That part is no problem.

I have however added a custom button which uploads a video, but not directly, but to vimeo using the vimeo API. So I have no actual file that has been uploaded in tinyMCE.

But now I want to show my users that a video has been uploaded by showing an image of a play button for example in the section where tinyMCE usually shows uploaded files.

I cannot seem to find any documentation on this.
Is there some kind of javascript function to add a 'fake' file to the list of uploaded files?